# The vampire everyone wants to kill (might be glitched)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim and I'm a vampire and I kept feeding off people so now everyone that sees me they try to attack me I can't even talk to the quest lady to cure the vampirism. What can I do to stop everyone from trying to kill me?

Comment: No this more difficult. I can't do nothing in the game without someone trying to attack me not even quest

Comment: @jonathan Drapeau

Comment: If you are at the stage 4, you will be attacked on sight. `NPCs will attack you on sight once you hit stage 4` as noted in the first answer. Also, it might be just that you are branded a criminal everywhere cause `Must feed periodically to maintain lower-levels of vampirism, which is a real hassle and is considered a crime`

Comment: The answer in the question Jonathan linked to states that becoming a Werewolf cures Vampirism, so if you can do that it's a route to getting cured.